# AlertDialog show chosen result from RadioButton, make users check again

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm beginner from Android Studio.I don't know how to resolve my qiestion.There is a fragment that I would like user choose what they like in Radio Group which has own three radio buttons.Before they send their result to another fragment,I need to pop up Alert dialog let user check again what they choose.Is there any way could collect all button result and show it to users ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button, container, false);

    RadioGroup rgdSize = view.findViewById(R.id.rdgSize);
    rgdSize.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {

                case (R.id.rdbSmall):

                    break;

                case (R.id.rdbMedium):

                    break;

                case (R.id.rdbLarge):

                    break;
            }


        }
    });

    RadioGroup rgdRank = view.findViewById(R.id.rdgRank);
    rgdRank.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch (i) {

                case (R.id.rdbFirst):

                    break;

                case (R.id.rdbSecond):

                    break;

                case (R.id.rdbThird):

                    break;
            }


        }
    });


    Button btnSend;
    btnSend = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(btnSendListener);

    return view;
}

private Button.OnClickListener btnSendListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.btnSend:
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("Please make sure you choose correct")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                            }
                        })

                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                            }
                        })
                        .show();

        }

        }

    };
}
```

Here's my XML

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/rdgSize">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Size"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbSmall"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbMedium"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbLarge"/>


</RadioGroup>


<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rdgSize"
    android:id="@+id/rdgRank">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="Rank"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbFirst"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbSecond"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/rdbThird"/>


</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rdgRank"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this, you can make your radiogroups universal:

```
  RadioGroup rgdSize,rgdRank;

 @Nullable
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
 ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button, container, false);

 rgdSize = view.findViewById(R.id.rdgSize);
 rgdRank = view.findViewById(R.id.rdgRank);

 Button btnSend;
btnSend = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
btnSend.setOnClickListener(btnSendListener);

return view;
 }
```

Replace your alertdialog code with this one:

```
         private Button.OnClickListener btnSendListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.btnSend:
            int selectedId = rgdSize.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        int selectedId2 = rgdRank.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);

      String result = radioButton.getText()+""+radioButton2.getText();



           new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Please make sure you choose correct")
                    .setMessage(""+result)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        }
                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new 
              DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        }
                    })
                    .show();

    }

    }

};
```

Comment: Where should I add  in or do something ? I try to change many places.It seems it can't find rgdSize and rgdRank .

Comment: replace the code of alert dialog which is written after this line " case R.id.btnSend:" & make both of radiogroup universal in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`rgdRank.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` to get the checked radiobutton id.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)rgdRank.findViewById(rgdRank.getCheckedRadioButtonId());//get checked radiobutton
String s =  rb.getText(); //get text of this checked radiobutton
```

After this, using `String` class function to display what you want.